# Prevent deleting string from textbox after reaching certain length in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, string, dom-events

I want to prevent the user from deleting certain length of string from textbox in AngularJS.

I want some text like "abcd" to be fixed in textbox such that user cannot delete it. It would act like **pre-string**.

For that I have initialized the textbox with **ng-init** and on **keyup** event I'm checking the length of string, if it is less than predefined size then I'm putting the string back in the **ng-model**.

It's working with no errors, but not smoothly. I want to prevent pressing **backspace** or **delete** button if the text reached to specified length while deleting the text from textbox.

I am new to **AngularJS**.

Here is the [**Plunker**](http://plnkr.co/edit/BKUeg8dhdVqXmIyeMDxh) link.

**HTML**

```
<body ng-app="myApp1">
  <div ng-controller="myController">
    <div ng-app>
      <label>Key:</label>
      <input type="text" name="key" ng-model="key" ng-init="key = 'abcd'" ng-keyup="updateKey($event)">
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

**AngularJS**

```
(function(angular) {
  'use strict';
  var myApp = angular.module('myApp1', []);

  myApp.controller('myController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
    $scope.updateKey = function($event) {
      var len = $scope.key.length;
      if ($event.keyCode === 8 && len < 4) {
        $scope.key = "abcd";
      }
    };
  }]);
})(window.angular);
```

Comment: need to use ngModel parsers in a directive for this. Numerous conditions like paste you aren't considering, or user just putting cursor in that part

Comment: @charlietfl can you please provide any example?

Comment: see examples in docs .. or do a google search

Comment: Do you really want such a strage UI experiecen or would a validation for the minimum length also work?

Comment: @billc.cn I have seen such examples in jQuery, if I provide minimum length then I have to do it on either lost focus or form submit, which I dont want.

Comment: What if someone adds 15 characters and then moves the cursor tot he front and deletes 15 characters. Sounds like you are solving the wrong problem to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can setup a explicit `$watcher` function for the `$scope.key`

```
$scope.$watch('key', function(newValue, oldValue) {
  console.log(oldValue, newValue);
  if(newValue.length < 4) {
    $scope.key = 'abcd';
  }
});
```

watcher function will call every time when the model is change, so when you change the model angular will call this function, in the function we can get the `old` value and `new` value based on that you can do what you try to achive.

here is the [DEMO](http://plnkr.co/edit/62jQKEmVD5J7G7eX4FCt?p=preview)

Comment: Thanks @K.Toress
I tried this but I am getting error newValue is undefined

Comment: did you check the demo its working well in the demo, remove the `ng-keyup`

Comment: Its working, I have added code for checking null value for newValue before newValue.length

Comment: gal to help you :) cheerz